# How do I find the openssl libraries on Linux (Debian buster)

Tags: linux, installation, openssl

I need to find the path to the OpenSSL libraries (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) on my Linux system, and suspected they could be located where the OpenSSL.exe resides.

If I enter

```
openssl version
```

I get a response like "OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019". Great, so OpenSSL is installed.

If I enter

```
whereis openssl
```

I get "openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz" and would suspect that this was the oppenssl installation directory.

Unfortunately, that directory does not exist, and so doesn't /usr/local/ssl, which is, so Internet sources say, another popular installation directory for OpenSSL. Nevertheless, OpenSSL works.

Not even a full recursive search of the file system from root reveals a hit on any of those OpenSSL files.

How do I find them? Why does whereis fail?

Comment: Why does whereis fail, and what does the path it returns mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian (or GNU/Linux system in general) don't use .dll files for OpenSSL. There are no such files as `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`.  On Debian Buster you can find OpenSSL shared libraries `libcrypto.co.1.1` and `libssl.so.1.1` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (depending on your CPU architecture).

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the above answer

you can even try to use `apt-file` since it will search for the regex you provide, remember that you need to install it first

oneline install

```
apt install apt-file && apt-file update
apt-file search ssleay32.dll
```

but i agree with @alexd theres usually no dll and exe files on Linux/unix systems